# Value of LEN_TRIM on a variable

Tags: fortran

I have this Fortran code where I want to determine how many (valid) entries a 1-dimension character variable (`dummy`) has. Therefor I use `LEN_TRIM` to check if the length of the actual entry is greater than 0:

```
program test

implicit none

integer :: x1, x2
character(len=10), dimension(2) :: dummy

dummy(1) = "VALUE"

x1 = LEN_TRIM(dummy(1))
x2 = LEN_TRIM(dummy(2))

end program
```

Here both `x1` and `x2` have the value 10. However, if I change the code to:

```
x1 = LEN_TRIM('VALUE ')
x2 = LEN_TRIM('   ')
```

`x1` becomes 5 and `x2` becomes 0.

Why are both variants lead to different results? I am using the Intel compiler.

Comment: Given you don't define the value of `dummy(2)` in the first case, why do you expect `len_trim(dummy(2))` to return anything of value?

Comment: which version of the Intel compiler are you using?

Comment: I think it should return 0, shouldn't it?
And I use Intel(R) Visual Fortran Compiler XE 13.0.1.119

Comment: Not initialized means it can contain anything. Compiler version is a bit old isn't it (though I cannot test it as I don't have either compiler, but looks like a bug in the old compiler),

Comment: Allright. Thanks Albert. I know that the compiler is old, but our company does not provide us any newer one. I need to find another way.

Comment: It shouldn't return 0.  The program is invalid and the compiler is allowed to return anything.  In particular, if you do `print *, dummy(2)` you'll likely see the junk `len_trim` considers not to be spaces.

Comment: Oddly, I cannot find anywhere in the standard what happens when you pass an undefined variable to the `len_trim` function (or the constraint that the argument must be defined)...

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues, there is nothing terribly special about `len_trim` to merit special mention. The function result depends on the _value_ of the argument: the argument is referenced and must therefore be defined.  This can be contrasted with the function `len` which doesn't depend on the value.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues The very concept of undefined behavior (in C lingo) is based on the fact that the behavior is not described by the standard. In Fortran we say that the code is not standard conforming, but here it is really the same as the undefined behavior in C.

Comment: Yeah, I get it. I am saying that Fortran Standard *do* defines what makes something undefined, but I failed to find the constraint saying if or in which contexts they are accepted / rejected (in fact, it is not listed as a processor dependent stuff), except for specific texts, like intrinsic inquire functions saying that the parameter can even be undefined.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues, comments here are not really suitable for such a discussion on when a variable must be defined, but if you wish to understand things in depth a question on that topic would be answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LEN_TRIM returns the length of the specified string **ignoring trailing blanks**. So, in the second example the results are perfectly correct. As for the first example, Try initializing dummy with `dummy=' '` and then do `dummy(1)='VALUE'`